# Creating horizontal list of auto sliding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a horizontal list of divs which slide rapidly from left to right every x seconds for my homepage. Here's what I've achieved so far: http://jsbin.com/rozurikina/1/

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="section_blue"></div>
    <div id="section_red"></div>
    <div id="section_green"></div>

  </div>
```

As you can see, I'm not able to align the three divs horizontally (I think it may be due to the width being set to 100%, but it's necessary as I'd prefer the div to take full width of the page) and moreover I am unsure of the jquery necessary to make the divs scroll rapidly every x seconds like a slideshow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to make your own slider? So you see just one color at a time?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad .... You are still too far from the final goal at least search first how to put aside your divs `float` or `inline-block` here on SO got tons of questions about that...Then go to the JS part searching about change position of an element.

Comment: How can something both "take the full width of the page" and be aligned horizontally. that makes 0 sense whatsoever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stackoverflow usually works that you post what you have tried and tell us what the problem is and we fix it for you, it's not meant for us to do the whole thing from the ground up. Anyway, since you're a beginner I don't want you to give up, so I built what I think you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/u5dn0mp5/

```js
var time = 2000;//milliseconds
var index = 0;
var container = $("#container");
var childrenCount = $(".section").length;
function slideToNext() {

    index = (index + 1) % childrenCount;
    console.log(index);
    container.css({
        marginLeft: -1 * index * 100 + "%"
    })
}
var pt = window.setInterval(function() {
    slideToNext();
}, time)
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-x: hidden;}

#container {
    width: 300%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
        transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.section {
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

#section_blue {background: blue;}
#section_red {background: red;}
#section_green {background: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

    <div class="section" id="section_blue"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section_red"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section_green"></div>

  </div>
```

We use floats to make the divs align horizontally. Their width is set to 33.3333% of their parent which has a width of 300%; the result is that each color is 100% wide as the body.

Then we give a negative margin to the container in order to move it around.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

This may be a slick configuration for your issue.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#container').slick({
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      autoplaySpeed: 500,
      autoplay: true,
      slidesToShow: 1
    });
});
```

Style your container with 100% width for full width slideshow.

For more configuration options check the [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings).